# Is there a more elegant way to get the Internet Expolor version with AutoIt

Tags: internet-explorer, autoit, comobject

**Summary:**

I'm looking for a more elegant way to get the Internet Explorer (*IE*) version on a windows computer (especially with AutoIt, because of the compiled *.exe). My current solution (follows below) do the job, but maybe there is a better way with pure AutoIt function(s) (UDFs)?

**Background and goal:**

I have to check for a specific *IE* versions and in general for versions lower then 11 (11.0.9600).

- [information-about-internet-explorer-versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/969393/information-about-internet-explorer-versions)

There are round 60 devices (server, laptops, etc.) which I have to check. The compiled *.exe will find the version and set a entry of that information (besides some other like hostname and so on) to a small HTML report. That remote processing and execution isn't a problem.

**Code:**

```cpp
#include-once
#include <Array.au3>

Func _getFileProperties( $sDirectory, $sFileName, $bRemoveEmptyLines = True )
    Local $oShellApp           = ObjCreate( 'Shell.Application' )
    Local $oFolder             = $oShellApp.NameSpace( $sDirectory )
    Local $oFolderItem         = $oFolder.Parsename( $sFileName )
    Local $aPropertyList[1][2] = [[1]]

    For $i = 0 To 400 Step 1
        If $oFolder.GetDetailsOf( $oFolder.Items, $i ) Then
            ReDim $aPropertyList[$aPropertyList[0][0] + 1][2]
            $aPropertyList[$aPropertyList[0][0]][0] = $oFolder.GetDetailsOf( $oFolder.Items, $i )
            $aPropertyList[$aPropertyList[0][0]][1] = $oFolder.GetDetailsOf( $oFolderItem, $i )
            $aPropertyList[0][0] += 1
        EndIf
    Next
    _ArraySort( $aPropertyList, 0, 1, 0 )

    If $bRemoveEmptyLines Then
        For $i = $aPropertyList[0][0] - 1 To 1 Step - 1
            If $aPropertyList[$i][1] == '' Then _ArrayDelete( $aPropertyList, $i )
        Next
    EndIf

    $aPropertyList[0][0] = UBound( $aPropertyList, 1 ) - 1
    Return $aPropertyList
EndFunc

Global $aPropertyList = _getFileProperties( @SystemDir, 'ieframe.dll' )
_ArrayDisplay( $aPropertyList )
```

**Current result:**

Of course I will filter the array for my search criteria (no problem).

[image]

**Expected result:**

Is basicly the same as above (current result) but maybe in a faster way and also with AutoIt own/native function(s)? Because it's just a step of many other information which will be gathered and I try to reduce the code and to improve the readability for future editings.

Please notice that I can check for 
`_getFileProperties( @SystemDir, 'ieframe.dll' )`or for
`_getFileProperties( $sPathIe, 'iexplore.exe' )`.
Both do provide the version information.

Is there an other way, more elegant and AutoIt own/native function to achieve my goal?

Comment: `FileGetVersion("c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe","ProductVersion")`?

Comment: Thank you @Stephan. To be honest I didn't know that possibility (function). But unfortunately that function returns a **different version** then my solution with the properties.

*11.00.9600.19236* (Property) versus *11.00.9600.16428* (FileGetVersion).
I will compare the results for the other computers (server, laptop etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check registry details as well to verify IE version.Hope this might help you to find it other way.

```
;Internet Explorer version is
Global $svcVersion = (RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer", "svcVersion"))
If $svcVersion <> "" Then
    MsgBox(1, "internet Explorer Version" , "Internet Explorer version is: " & $svcVersion)
Endif
```

OR

```
;Internet Explorer updated version is
Global $svcUpdateVersion = (RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer", "svcUpdateVersion"))
If $svcUpdateVersion <> "" Then
    MsgBox(1, "internet Explorer Version" , "Internet Explorer updated version is: " & $svcUpdateVersion)
Endif
```

Comment: I have to try it for the other computers (server, laptop etc.). But *svcVersion* is a working approach which giving me the correct version like *11.00.9600.19236*.

Comment: Great to know that is what you look after.